# /usr/bin/env: ruby 1.8: No such file or

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I'm working with Xubuntu 11.04.

I do not succeed to have `thin` running at server startup.

when I try the command:

```
/etc/init.d/thin start
```

I get the following message:

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby 1.8: No such file or ...
```

But the commands `ruby -v` is working fine and the result is `ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel334) Ruby enterprise`
`rails -v` is also working fine and the result is `Rails 2.3.5`

If I do the command `sudo thin -C configfile.yml start` then the thin server is starting without any issue.

Why can't it be started with the server? What can I do to have it working?

The `thin` script is a usual one which is working fine on a [Debian-lenny](https://www.debian.org/releases/lenny/)

Comment: run `which ruby` and see where your ruby is installed. and change the paths accordingly.

Comment: Looks like your current PATH environment variable includes directory where ruby binary is located but when /etc/init.d/thin script is executed it is not there.

Comment: which ruby give /usr/local/bin/ruby the script for starting thin has in the first line #!/bin/sh

Comment: Are you using a mixture of Ubuntu package manager installed Ruby and libraries with manually installed ones, because that may explain your conflict. If possible I recommend installing through RVM or just manually in it's own path.

Comment: What happens when you directly type in ```thin start```?

Answer (score 1):

I got the some error when using `sudo gem install unicorn`, and find a solution [here](http://www.lunarforums.com/ruby_hosting_support/usrbinenv_ruby_no_such_file_or_directory-t40138.0.html). When ruby is not installed in the location /usr/bin/ruby, you need give a full path of ruby which means you need to use command like follows:

```
/full/path/to/ruby /etc/init.d/thin start
```

Hope this also works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The header of your file should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

If you include any additional arguments they should be flags for ruby itself, as others may be interpreted as a script name.

What you may have is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env "ruby 1.8"
```

Unless you have an executable named `ruby 1.8` including the space, that won't work.

Comment: the first line of my thin script is #!/bin/sh

Comment: There must be some other script involved with a header like that, or something in your configuration that launches it that way.